# Out of memory error while using GPU for video dataset

Tags: keras, out-of-memory, gpu

my dataset size is about 5GB including 2000 short videos. I am using a system with 8 x 32GB GPUs.
But, when I run my code in epoch 7 (sometimes it also happens in 6,8,9). [This is the error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb1PN.png)
As it shows, the error happens in GPU[0], while we have 8 GPUs, (GPU[0],GPU[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb1PN.png),GPU[2],GPU[3],GPU[4],GPU[5],GPU[6],GPU[7]). I have no idea whether the server uses GPUs sequentially or parallel. How should I define and active GPUs at first to get rid of this error message?
Please help me to solve this run out of memory error.

Thanks,

Comment: Your error message is weird. Initially, add those couple of lines in top of your code and specify the gpu number (I used 2 as an example): `os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID" os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"` .. and let's see what would be the error :)

Comment: Please add errors as text, not images. Your error has literally nothing to do with out of memory, it seems to be a reshaping problem